# Is there any way I can update a mounted React node's props in my current setup?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

So I have a mounted React application that is rendered like this (it's via another framework on top):

```
const componentRender = (entryComponent, initialProps, targetNode) => {
  root.render(wrapper);
}
```

On top level, I call a 3rd party library and wrap my React application inside of it.

What's the best way to integrate React inside of a 3rd party library that its supposed to render into?

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to update props within a component, not outside of the render function. Otherwise, as you've said, it will cause a full remount.

So the solution would be to call your `Ext.extend` function from within the `App` component.

```
 function App() {
    const [ready, setReady] = useState(false);
    const [props, setProps] = useState({});

    // Calls once on first mount.
    useEffect(() => {
      Ext.extend(Ext.Container, {
        listeners: {
          afterrender: function () {
           setProps(this.myProps);
           setReady(true);
          },
        },
       constructor: function (...args) {
          Object.assign(this, args);
        },
        onServerSuccess: function(data) {
        // here is where I receive new data 
          setProps(data);
        }
      });
    }, [])

    return (
      ready ? <Component {...props} /> : null
    );
  }

ReactDOM.render(App, rootNode);
```

If there is more interaction between `Ext` and the react component, for example you need to pass `this.root` into a function, you can still do that with the normal DOM APIs like `document.getElementById`. Or you can add it like this:

```
// use this reference to do stuff with the react object
this.root = <Component {...props} />

return this.root;
```

but changing the react component object directly would be an anti-pattern. All state/props updates should happen using APIs provided by the react library.

Also if for some reason you need to render the react component directly inside the `Ext.Container` node, then you should use `ReactDOM.createPortal` instead of `render`.

Here's how that would look.

```
  import { createPortal } from 'react-dom';

  const Portal = memo(({ children, domNode }) => createPortal(
    children,
    domNode,
  ));

 function App() {
    const [ready, setReady] = useState(false);
    const [props, setProps] = useState({});

    // Calls once on first mount.
    useEffect(() => {
      Ext.extend(Ext.Container, {
        listeners: {
          afterrender: function () {
           setProps(this.myProps);
           setReady(true);
          },
        },
       constructor: function (...args) {
          Object.assign(this, args);
        },
        onServerSuccess: function(data) {
        // here is where I receive new data 
          setProps(data);
        }
      });
    }, [])
    
    return (
      ready ? 
       <Portal domNode={extComponentNode}>
         <Component {...props} />
       </Portal> : null
    );
  }
```

Where `extComponentNode` is the node you want it rendered in. `createPortal` allows the react component to share state with your react App even though it's rendered in a different place, without the issue of calling `render` again.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to re-render the component with updated states without unmounting-mouting it whenever the prop(s) passed to the component changes.

Create a `useEffect` inside this component to re-render the component whenever the required prop(s) changes. To do this, add the prop(s) for which you want to re-render the component in the dependency array of `useEffect` and pass a function that will update the states of the component.

```js
useEffect(  
<function which will update the states, causing re-rendering of the component>,  
[ <all props for which you want to run the function separated by a comma> ]  
)
```